# Why bold faces do not inherit from the `bold` face?

Tags: faces, customize, customize-face

I had tried to use a `thin` weight font as the `default` face and a `regular` weight font as the `bold` face (try, it's a nice combination), but I desisted because there are a zillion faces that do not inherit from `bold` but explicitly set the `weight` property to `bold`, so that I should manually customize a zillion faces…

I'd like to know if the Emacs developers/maintainers have ever provided a reason for them explicitly setting the weight to `bold`, when it is possible to specify that such faces inherit from `bold` leading to a single point of modification.

Comment: For this kind of question I recommend sending mail to `help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`. But perhaps you'll get an authoritative answer here.

Comment: Emacs face definitions are a mess. There are far too many faces defined in Emacs and in third party packages, this makes it almost impossible to define a theme that cover them all. What we should do is to 1) define a set of base faces (100 or so would do) and encourage everyone to inherit from them, and 2) write a style guide on how to define your own faces, including which faces to inherit from etc (the latter would solve your problem). Unfortunately, this is a huge undertaking so we need someone with time and energy to spear-head it.